# What happens when you conquer a city where a spaceship is under construction?

Tags: civilization-5

What happens when you conquer a city where a spaceship is under construction? Can the conquered civilization continue construction in its new capital? Does the conquered civilization retain its already-constructed modules? Do you get to capture the already-constructed modules as your own?

Note : I am talking about modules that have already been added to the spaceship, not ones who are still walking around as units.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The conquered civilization can continue constructing the spaceship in its new capital - an appropriate spaceship model will actually appear in the new capital as well.

The conquered civilization retains all its already-constructed modules, and does not need to build them again.

The conquering civilization does not get access to any of the constructed modules.